# Confused between array and objects in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel-4

I'm learning Laravel and it uses OOPS concepts. Now I'm finding it hard to understand the real difference between array and objects. I actually know what an array and object is.

Array can hold more than one variable where as an object is an independent entity which has its own arguments and methods. We usually use foreach loop to loop through them.

In laravel, data is returned in the form of model instance as object. When the query response has multiple results, then data is returned in the form of an array which contains objects. I was trying to understand Collection Class used in laravel.

Codebright reference says

> The Collection class itself, is merely a wrapper for an array of objects, but has a bunch of other interesting methods to help you pluck items out of the array.

Now coming back to my confusion. I was using different methods like `all()` and `first()` methods to fetch the result. But sometimes when i used arrow (`->`) to fetch the data using a foreach loop, from an object (contained in an array), it showed an error that says something like it is a non object. Then I used square brackets and the data was displayed.

I know we use `[]` to fetch data from arrays and we use `->` to fetch data from objects. But I'm still confused about Laravel. Can someone clearly state the difference between them in reference to Collection class used in Laravel?

Edit:: The confusion began while using this code:

```
foreach($self_conversations as $self_conversations_fetch){
    //fetching each conversation id
    $conversation_id = Conversation::find($self_conversations_fetch->conversation_id);
    $user_id = array();

//fetching each conversation member's id
    foreach($conversation_id->conversationsMember as $conversationmembers)
        $user_id[] = $conversationmembers->user_id;

        $self_id = User::where('email', Session::get('email'))->first()->id;
        $self_id_array = array($self_id);
        $friend_id_array = array_diff($user_id, $self_id_array);

        foreach($friend_id_array as $friend_id) array_push($friend_ids, $friend_id);

    $conversations_reply_obj = ConversationReply::where('conversation_id', $self_conversations_fetch->conversation_id)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();

    $conversations_reply[] = $conversations_reply_obj['reply'];
}
```

As you can see, i have used square brackets to fetch the data(in the last line).

```
$conversations_reply[] = $conversations_reply_obj['reply'];
```

i was expecting arrow to work here

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually the `Collection` class is a wrapper object which returns a collection of objects. For example, if you have a Model for example, `User` then you may use it in various ways, to get all records you may use `User::all()` and to get a single record you may use `User::find(1)` and there are other ways as well.

If you use `all()`, `get()` methods then you'll get a collection object, it means a collection of `User` models when you use these methods on `User` model and remember `all()` and `get()` always returns a collection of models even if there is only one model in it, so check this examaple:

```
$users = User::all(); // returns a collection
```

You may use `first()` method of `Collection` object like this:

```
$users = User::all();
$users->first();
```

Or directly just:

```
$user = User::first();
```

You may also use `last` to get the last item/model from the collection. You may also use `get()` like this:

```
$users = User::all();
$users = User::get(0) // to get first item/model
$users = User::get(1) // to get second item/model
```

You may also use a loop like this:

```
$users = User::get(); // same as all
// pass the collection to the view
return View::make('users.index')->with('users', $users);
```

Now in your `views/users/index.blade.php` view you may use a loop like this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->username }}<br />
    {{ $user->email }}<br />
@endforeach
```

It's important to knoe that, `all()` and `get()` methods returns a collection and `first()` and `find(id)` returns a single model object, so if you have a single model then you may directly use it like this:

```
$user = user::find(1); // 1 is id for example
return View::make('users.index')->with('user', $user);
```

In your view you may use:

{{ $user->email }}

You may use an object using `->` for example `$user->name` and an array using `$user['name']` but in this case you may use both syntax because `Laravel`'s `Eloquent/Model` implements `ArrayAccess` (along with others) interface so every model that extends `Eloquent` could be used using both array and object syntax to access properties. So, following is possible:

```
$user = User::where('username', 'me')->get();
return View::make('users.index')->with('user', $user);
```

In the `view` you may use:

```
{{ $user->name }}
{{ $user['name'] }}
```

For better understanding of the `Collection` class and it's methods check the source code, you may find it at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php` of your local installation and it extends `Illuminate/Support/Collection.php` class. Check both classes. You may also read [this article](http://heera.it/extend-laravel-eloquent-collection-object#.U0HGMvmSySo), it'll help you more.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know the source of your problem, as I've been having to work around it.  If you are using the arrow notation on a model object and there is no record in the relationship, then you'll get the "non-object" error.  For example, if you have the line

```
$student->school->school_name
```

and a given `$student` doesn't have a `school` object, you'll get the non-object error.  I typically add checks for `empty($student->school)` or `empty($student->school_id)` or the like to avoid this when I run into it (or heaven forbid forsee the problem when doing my initial coding pass).

EDIT:  So, to clarify, Laravel doesn't say "oh, there's a relationship there, so `school` is an object which happens to be empty, so I'll return null for `school_name`", it says "there's no `school`, so `->school_name` is an invalid call to an object property"