# How to extract each of the items from an array? laravel/php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, laravel, laravel-5

I have 50 items in an array that looks something like this:

```
     array:50 [▼
      0 => {#253 ▼
        +"message": "message_1"
        +"created_time": {#254 ▼
          +"date": "2016-03-03 07:54:05.000000"
          +"timezone_type": 1
          +"timezone": "+00:00"
        }
        +"id": "167633226631991_1051771021551536"
      }
      1 => {#255 ▼
        +"message": "message_2"
        +"created_time": {#256 ▼
          +"date": "2016-03-02 13:35:26.000000"
          +"timezone_type": 1
          +"timezone": "+00:00"
        }
        +"id": "167633226631991_1051313571597281"
      }
    ]
```

I need to grab each variable within the array. But I keep getting an error that reads:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$message
```

Im not sure what Im missing I've tried doing:

```
     foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $test = array('message' => $post->message );
     }
```

and also

```
$a = -1;

$alpha = 0;

$omega = count($posts);

$empty_array = array();

foreach (range($alpha,$omega) as $i) {
  ++$a;
  $test = $posts[$a]->message;
  array_push($empty_array, $test);
  }
```

but I'm getting the same error. Im using laravel 5.2.

Update:
The array is coming from facebook's graph API. I am converting the json format using:

```
$posts = json_decode($userNode['posts']);
```

Doing this then displays the `array:50` as above.

Comment: Try to write $post['message']

Comment: What does `dd($post)` show within the foreach?

Comment: @RaviHirani I tried $post['message'] I get this error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: @Joseph if I `dd($post)` I get `{#253 ▼
  +"message": "message_1"
  +"created_time": {#254 ▼
    +"date": "2016-03-03 07:54:05.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 1
    +"timezone": "+00:00"
  }
  +"id": "167633226631991_1051771021551536"
}`

Comment: Where is this array coming from in the first place, and what is the code used to generate it? Please update this information in the question rather than as a comment as it's easier to read.

Comment: @Joseph. Updated the post to include where the array is coming from. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the array is an array of objects, you are referencing it correctly when you type `$post->message`. Doing `$post['message']` won't work because it is not an array of arrays.

I believe that the `Undefined property: stdClass::$message` error is coming about because some of the objects in your `$posts` array have an empty `+message` or a non-existent `+message`

The best way to deal with this is to use an `isset()`. However, you also need to change your `$test` to `$test[]` to stop it from being overwritten each time it loops.

The code:

```
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        isset($post->message) ? $test[] = array('message' => $post->message ) : null;
    }
```

After that, `dd($test)` will provide you with an array of arrays with the message in.

If you actually just wanted a plain array of messages then do this:

```
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        isset($post->message) ? $test[] = $post->message : null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @Joseph: Nice answer brother :) Perhaps in laravel object can be accessible as array also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897919/confused-between-array-and-objects-in-laravel

Comment: You can also just use the Laravel helper `array_pluck($posts, 'message')` :)

Comment: @RaviHirani You're right, in some cases they are interchangeable. However, in this specific case, accessing `$post['message']` would result in `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: Agree with you my friend. This is not the case :-) BTW my name is Ravi not others as you have mentioned in your answer ;-)

Comment: @Joost Yes, array_pluck would mean we don't have to use the foreach, but it would also add `null` values (when there was no `$post->message`) to the array wouldn't it? I suppose we could get around wrapping this in an `array_filter()` though, couldn't we? Can you think of a cleaner way?

Comment: @RaviHirani My apologies, I have edited the answer. :-)