# Error is showing When I am trying to fetch details according to Id in Popup In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am fetching the details of a user according to Id on button click in a popup in laravel but It is showing some error.

This is viewuser.blade.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$usersview->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$usersview->firstname}}</td>
                    <td>{{$usersview->filename}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
  </div>
```

This is viewparticipant.blade.php in which I have a button View. When the user will click on this button a popup will open and show the details according to Id.

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ URL::to('participant/show',$row->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View</a>
</td>
```

My Controller:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
use App\Imageupload;

 class ParticipantController extends Controller
 {
     public function show($id)
     { 
         $usersview = Imageupload::find($id);
         return View::make('viewuser', compact('usersview')); 
     }
 }
```

My Web.php

```
Route::get('/participant/show/{id}','ParticipantController@show');
```

The error is showing that unknown variables in modal.

Comment: viewuser.blade.php and viewparticipant.blade.php are in same view?(subview)?

Comment: In viewparticipant.blade.php, I am fetching 20 users which have Id in Table and In the table, I have View button for all. In viewuser.blade.php I have the modal which will show the details of the particular user. I have included that Model in viewparticipant.blade.php. @ab_in

Comment: I have uploaded the Project On Github. https://github.com/rahulpamnani1234/CRUD

Comment: your github link doesn't matches with your question!. (Probably last few commits needs to be pushed).

Comment: if you are included your `viewuser.blade.php` in your `viewparticipant.blade.php`, then both are rendered simultaneously and expects variables of `$usersview` which does not have a value on rendering.(user have to trigger another url for data) so you may have to load empty modal and use ajax request for filling selected user data in the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you only have $usersview in your blade file and you're calling $row->id in viewparticipant.blade.php , which should be the $usersview->id instead

after Edit -->
so you need to make an ajax call to the function you want to get the results. the ajax must contain the id of the user so you should get the id some how. I usually define an on click function and get the id. then on the same click trigger an ajax call, something like this:

```
$('#user').on('click', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/users?user_id=' + $(this).val(),
        success: function (data) {
            // parse the data
        },
        fail: function () {
            // do something in case of failure
        }
    });
});
```

$(this).val(); is the id here, I assumed you would store that in an input

Comment: In viewparticipant.blade.php, I am fetching the whole Data. $row->id is the Id of a particular user that I want to fetch details in Popup.

Comment: well then it seems like you're not even getting the user info, every time the bottom is click you need to fie an ajax request to retrieve the user info, or I didn't get what it is that you actually want

Comment: Yes, When I am sending the info on other page it is showing the details but In Popup It is not showing. I think It will be done by Ajax.@Hamid Vetr. Can You do the code??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<td>
<a href="{{ URL::to('participant/show/{id}',$row->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View</a>
</td>
```

Because laravel is figuring out where you want to place your $row->id variable, and to my guessing it's not passing the variable correctly in your route.

Comment: In viewparticipant.blade.php, I am fetching the whole Data. $row->id is the Id of a particular user that I want to fetch details in Popup.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
@foreach($usersview as $usersview)
<tr>
 <td>{{$usersview->id}}</td>
 <td>{{$usersview->firstname}}</td>
 <td>{{$usersview->filename}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: In this page, I am fetching only one user.@WeerakoonNB. So why @foreach loop.

Comment: so, i think i'm wrong then. refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897919/confused-between-array-and-objects-in-laravel